# Should you hedge theta?

Tags: interest-rates, hedging

Consider an arbitraty interest rate derivative $C$. Assume that in order to hedge it, you are allowed to construct portfolio $H$ of linear combination of simple instruments such as Interest Rate Swaps (IRS) and Forward Rate Agreement (FRA). By construction such portfolio is not self-financing. During some time interval, for example 1 week, you want to have change in value of your hedging portfolio $H$ equal to the change in value of $C$, i.e.:
$$E^P[(\Delta H(w)-\Delta C)^2]=0$$ or $$argmin_wE^P[(\Delta H(w)-\Delta C)^2]$$ where $w$ is vector of units of each trade (IRSes and FRAs) in the hedging portfolio $H$, the superscript $P$ indicates physical measure.

Should you consider time passage (theta) in order to construct hedging portfolio $H$?